# Using TouchImageView (external class) for gestures with image

Tags: android, imageview

I tried using TouchImageView which I found in https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

But I got an error :

```
02-05 12:46:05.508: E/AndroidRuntime(21710): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 12:46:05.508: E/AndroidRuntime(21710): Process: com.km.parkit, PID: 21710
02-05 12:46:05.508: E/AndroidRuntime(21710): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.km.parkit/com.km.parkit.MainMap}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to com.km.parkit.TouchImageView
02-05 12:46:05.508: E/AndroidRuntime(21710):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
02-05 12:46:05.508: E/AndroidRuntime(21710):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
02-05 12:46:05.508: E/AndroidRuntime(21710):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
02-05 12:46:05.508: E/AndroidRuntime(21710):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
02-05 12:46:05.508: E/AndroidRuntime(21710):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-05 12:46:05.508: E/AndroidRuntime(21710):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-05 12:46:05.508: E/AndroidRuntime(21710):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-05 12:46:05.508: E/AndroidRuntime(21710):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-05 12:46:05.508: E/AndroidRuntime(21710):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-05 12:46:05.508: E/AndroidRuntime(21710):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-05 12:46:05.508: E/AndroidRuntime(21710):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-05 12:46:05.508: E/AndroidRuntime(21710): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to com.km.parkit.TouchImageView
02-05 12:46:05.508: E/AndroidRuntime(21710):    at com.km.parkit.MainMap.onCreate(MainMap.java:16)
02-05 12:46:05.508: E/AndroidRuntime(21710):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
02-05 12:46:05.508: E/AndroidRuntime(21710):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
02-05 12:46:05.508: E/AndroidRuntime(21710):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
```

Is that because I had wrongly used the class?

I used it in another class named MainMap :

```
TouchImageView image;
image = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.overview);
```

Comment: Are you using `com.km.parkit.TouchImageView` in xml instead of `ImageView`

Comment: Change ImageView to com.km.parkit.TouchImageView  in your activity xml file.

Comment: I used ImageView, it appears that I should've used com.km.parkit.TouchImageView in the declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this :

```
TouchImageView img = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
```

If you are using TouchImageView in xml, then you must provide the full package
name, because it is a custom view. Example:

```
<com.km.parkit.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: I see, thanks. So I have to use the full package name if I'm using a custom image view. Thanks a lot, you gave me a new insight in Android coding.

Comment: Use "<com.ortiz.touchview.TouchImageView" for the latest version as of the date of this comment